# Laravel 5 - Multiple relationships between same tables.. naming and syntax

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 tables (users and companies). Users have different roles (shopper, distributor, administrator,...). I have a working solution for shoppers and partially for distributors. I'm having a problem using eloquent to setup the second relationship for distributor users. In users table I have company_id key for shoppers. In companies table I have main_distributor_id key for distributors

Relations: One company can have multiple shopper users. One shopper user can be asigned to one company.

One company can have one distributor. One distributor can be asigned to multiple companies.

User model:

```php
/* used for shoppers */
public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}

/* what is the proper naming? */
public function mainDistributorCompanies() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company','main_distributor_id','id');
}
```

Company model:

```php
/* for shopper users.. */
public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'company_id');
}

/* What is the proper naming */
public function mainDistributorUsers() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User','id','main_distributor_id');
}
```

Companies controller:

```php
public function index(Request $request) {

/* is this the correct way to include the relationship? Naming? */
$companies = Company::with('mainDistributorUsers')->get();
return view('companies/index', compact('companies'));
}
```

Companies index view:

```php
@foreach($companies as $company)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $company->index }}</td>
        <td>{{ $company->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $company->address }}</td>

        <td>{{ $company->mainDistributorUsers->username }}</td> // error
        <td>{{ $company->mainDistributorUsers()->username }}</td> // error
        <td>{{ $company->username }}</td> // empty
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Did I choose the wrong relationship for distributors? Wrong naming?

Comment: Sidenote: `App\{Model}` and `{Model}::class` are synonymous; for readability pick one or the other, not both.

Comment: What's the error? Does every company have a `mainDistributorUsers`?

Comment: sry for the inconsistency - I was trying different combinations.. :) Error are different. From not defined relationship, undifined property,.... And not every company has a defined `mainDistributorUsers`. Some are null.

Comment: $company->mainDistributorUsers()->username  gives: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$username ;; $company->mainDistributorUsers->username gives: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: I need a left join for this one if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for companies without a `mainDistributorUsers`:

```php
@isset($company->mainDistributorUsers)
    {{ $company->mainDistributorUsers->username }}
@endisset
```

Or use the [`optional()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-optional) helper:

```php
{{ optional($company->mainDistributorUsers)->username }}
```

BTW: `mainDistributorUsers()` should be a `BelongsTo` relationship:

```php
public function mainDistributorUsers() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'main_distributor_id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas, but `main_distributor_id key` is in the companies table not in users table.

Comment: It works :) Thank you. One more question. Is there a simple way to enter "" empty string in the controller if I know that some keys are null?

Comment: Thank you for the `optional` option. I'll look into it. I need to check the relationship you suggested first. :)